# why my css transition is not working in react 18

Tags: css, reactjs

I tried many times to add a transition to eventBody, but it still not working.

**here's the code:

```
export function Event({ event }: EventProps) {
  const [showDropDown, setShowDropDown] = useState(false)

  return (
      <div className={styles.eventBody} hidden={!showDropDown}>
        <div className={styles.line}></div>
        <AttendeeList upcoming={true} attenders={attenders}></AttendeeList>
     </div>
  )
}
```

**CSS:

```
.eventBody {
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

.eventBody[hidden='true'] {
  display: none;
}
```

i tired to setShowDropDown after 100 ms second on every click on the header div, and also tried to use height in transition instead of all but nothing worked

Comment: `display: none` isn't something that can transition. You have to decide what kind of transition you want and use that instead, like `opacity: 0` or `height: 0` or whatever effect you want.

Comment: @GuyIncognito i want to use height but when i tried setting height to 0 it didn't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your css selector is wrong. Also, `display` is not an [animatable property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties).

```css
.eventBody {
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.eventBody[hidden] {
  height: 0;
}
```

Comment: i want to use height but when i tried setting height to 0 it didn't work either

Comment: You can only animate a fixed height, by default height is set to auto, which you cannot animate. You can however bypass this by using max-height but it's not ideal. If you want a true animation of height you need to calculate the container's height and toggle between it and 0.